# MySQL - Comparing dayname of two queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-date

I want to compare two columns `Assigned_Date` and `Expected_Delivery_Day` in my table and check if day has passed.

This is my table:

[image]

I tried to get the `dayofweek` for each column and compare the weight with `IF`, but im not sure how.

This is what i tried:

```
SELECT dayofweek(`Assigned_Date`) FROM `drvapp_routes`;

SELECT CASE 
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Sunday' THEN 0
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Monday' THEN 1
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Wednesday' THEN 3
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Thursday' THEN 4
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Friday' THEN 5
WHEN `Expected_Delivery_Day` = 'Saturday' THEN 6
ELSE NULL END AS EDD
from `drvapp_routes`;
```

Is this the right way? How do i compare two day names and see if `Assigned_Date` has passed the `Expected_Delivery_Day` ?

Comment: What format are both fields? if both are dates then normal comparison operators will work.

Comment: If Expected_delivery_day is just a Day Name Then how are you expecting this date comparison to work, please be a little more specific

Comment: Do you want the comparision inside the query result or do you handle that inside your code?

Comment: I feel like this logic is going to complicated. You care about the next occuring day of the week from the `assigned_date` I assume. So you may need to do some date math. Otherwise if you ship on a Thursday and expect delivery on Monday then 4 > 1, but if you ship on Monday and expect delivery on Thursday then 4 < 1.. like.. how would you rectify that the weekday has passed? Other than that, your first step with this logic is sound (converting string weekdays to number).

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eFFnU3uM).

Comment: @wchiquito thank you very much, it is perfect and what i needed exactly!

Comment: @JNevill i completely agree. We are changing it to a timestamp.

Comment: @Jbadminton one query to rule them all :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct, it was bad coding. But it is what it is and i tried with the method above.

Comment: @psykx Assigned_Date is string and the other is date.

Comment: @wchiquito please do not leave this page in an abandoned state by resolving the question via comment.  Please transfer your advice to an answer and explain it so that Thowzif can accept the answer and officially mark this page as resolved.